# Multiple markers at this line - Occurrence of 'bitmap'- bitmap cannot be resolved

Tags: android

Trying deal with bitmap but eclipse not cooperating with me ,when i tried to declare

```
 ArrayList<bitmap> attachmentList;
```

it shows error

```
Multiple markers at this line - Occurrence of 'bitmap'- bitmap cannot be resolved
```

Comment: sorry guys minor mistake

Comment: plz delete this question..

Comment: You can't delete a question once an answer has upvotes, but you *can* accept one of the answers, they both say the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

Class names start with an upper case letter. `Bitmap` is what you want.

Answer (score 3):

There is no class "bitmap". Java is case-sensitive, you need to change it to "Bitmap", e.g.:

```
ArrayList<Bitmap> attachmentList;
```